# Open Excel 2016 workbook using Microsoft Edge or Chrome, ActiveWorkbook Path and Filename set to local directory instead of internal web directory

Tags: excel, vba, google-chrome, path, microsoft-edge

Recently, the company upgraded to Windows 10 from Windows 7.  Along with the operating system upgrade, an upgrade to Office from 2010 to 2016 occurred.  The company is running a Visual Studio 2013 application that will download Excel workbooks to extract, view and modify (add, update, or delete) data using VBA.  The workbooks use ActiveWorkbook.Path and ActiveWorkbook.FileName to determine the environment to update.  If the ActiveWorkbook.Path or ActiveWorkbook.FileName contained “SERVER1” this meant the production environment but if either contained “SERVER2” this meant the development environment.  This functionality prevented users from using saved copies of the workbook and ultimately would update the wrong environment.  Since the company standard is to use a more modern browser, Microsoft Edge or Chrome, test revealed an issue in both browsers.  Both browsers download the file to either the local internet temporary file or local download directory.  After opening the downloaded file, the values for ActiveWorkbook.Path and ActiveWorkbook.FileName are the local directories.  As part of open functionality, the VBA code attempts to extract the server name from the ActiveWorkbook.Path and/or ActiveWorkbook.FileName.  Since the server name does not exists, the workbook defaults to the test environment.  Since the user does not have access to change the variable storing the server name, the user cannot use the workbook.

I do not want to hardcode the server into the workbook.  I do not want to rely on the user to select the appropriate environment.  I would like to workbook to open directly from the server.  I understand this could be a security issue but the users want it.

I research and cannot find a solution to this issue.  I would appreciate any suggestion to resolve this issue.

TIA
Anthony

Comment: There's very little here which would allow anyone to help you.  What specifically is different in Chome/Edge vs. IE ?  IE typically also downloads Excel files to a local directory, so you're missing some critical info regarding why the new browsers are different.  Also you've not told us anything about how your users access these files in the first place.  What is the relationship between your VS application and the user's browser?

Comment: The VS application running in the browser has a link to blank workbook with appropriate VBA code.  The application link opens the workbook through the browser, opening Microsoft Excel with the activeworkbook.path set to http:\\SERVER1\folderStructure and the activeworkbook.filename set to  \\SERVER1\folderStructure\WorkbookName.xlsm. Where as Microsoft Edge and Chrome appear to download the file and then you either open automatically or you need to manually open the file from the download folder.  This results in activeworkbook.path and filename reflecting the location on the local hard drive.

Comment: So this application is a browser add-in, or is it a web application?

Comment: standalone web application

Answer (score 0):

Based on additional discussion with co-workers and management regarding the standards for web browsers (use of a modern web browser, Microsoft Edge or Chrome, but final decision was not available), I discovered two possible solutions.

Chrome solution:
This solution I was able to test on a co-workers computer.  The link is:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd?hl=en-US

For Chrome, you will need to insert an Add-On called IE Tab.  After clicking the link, you will need to follow the instructions to download and add the Add-On.  The free version requires you click the IE-Tab icon every time you open Chrome to use it.  To have Chrome open IE-Tab automatic requires the purchase of license.

Microsoft Edge solution:
This solution I was not able to test on a co-workers computer due to insufficient administration rights. The link is:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode

Based on the description this solution appears to work for Microsoft Edge.

Both solution descriptions state the browser will render all webpages using Internet Explorer 11 rendering.

I hope this help others in resolving similar issues.

Anthony